# Show all x-show divs on button click in Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

This seems simple but can't quite figure it out.  I have three Divs that toggle based on the  selection, but I'm trying to also have a "view all" button that toggles to show all three divs.  I also am hoping to have the first Div show on load.

```
<div x-data="{ color: '' }">
  
    <button x-on:click="color='Yellow', color='Red', color='Orange'">Show All</button>

    <select x-model="color">
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        <option>Yellow</option>
    </select>
  
    <div x-show="color === 'Red'">Show on Load</div>
    <div x-show="color === 'Orange'">Orange</div>
    <div x-show="color === 'Yellow'">Yellow</div>
</div>
```

Link to [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/gacoduwije/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a dedicated 'All' state to show all items. The default value of `color` can be given at `x-data`.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ color: 'Red', defaultColor: 'Red' }"> 
    <button x-on:click="color = (color === 'All') ? defaultColor : 'All'">Show All</button>

    <select x-model="color">
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        <option>Yellow</option>
    </select>
  
    <div x-show="color === 'Red' || color === 'All'">Show on Load</div>
    <div x-show="color === 'Orange' || color === 'All'">Orange</div>
    <div x-show="color === 'Yellow' || color === 'All'">Yellow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind showing me how to make the "Show All" button a show / hide toggle?

Comment: Sure! I added a `defaultColor` variable that will be the default state after toggling.